# Understanding AJAX add_action usage in plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a WordPress Plugin called `wpschoolpress` and I found something unexpected in their code.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_AddStudent', 'wpsp_AddStudent' );
```

According to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), the first Parameter of `add_action()` should be `wp_ajax_` followed by the function name and the second parameter should be the function name. So in this case the Function name is `wpsp_AddStudent` but the postfix of the first parameter is not same as the function name. Can anyone please tell what this exactly means.

Comment: It is not required that the action has the same name as the function. The only thing required is the `wp_ajax_` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_`. What followup can be anything, but always tries to be unique to prevent conflicts. The second argument **must** be the function name though.

Comment: or a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Re-read the codex.  The portion after `wp_ajax_` is the _action key_ which is being passed in from the javascript.  The _second argument_ is the function name (`wpsp_AddStudent` in your case).  So, in the javascript, look for `AddStudent`, you'll find it part of an ajax call, which then triggers the PHP function `wpsp_AddStudent`.